# iTextg doesn't work on android kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, itextg

I'm building an android app using iTextg library for creating PDF document. When I run it on my android 5.0 lollipop device, it works just fine. However, when I run it on other device, such as HTC Desire 526G, which has android 4.4.2 kitkat, app crashes at the beginning. It builds just fine, but when I run it, it crashes, with this error: [image]

I'm using 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9' library and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The error 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' shows when it crashes, but it doesn't make sense because this error doesn't show when I ignore imported library itextg.

Comment: How do you expect us to read that image. Please include a text dump.

Comment: Someone downvoted your question (not me). Probably because your screen dump is unreadable. I am currently on a train, commuting to work, reading StackOverflow on my smartphone. Really, I can't decipher it on a tiny scree.

Comment: @micdo Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot clearly shows which the missing class is:

[image: Excerpt from screen shot]

The missing class is `com.lambda.terenac.fragments.ImageGalleryFragment$1` which clearly is not an iText class but an anonymous inner class of your own `ImageGalleryFragment` class. Thus, you might want to rebuild your application and, if that does not help, check your tool chain.